# Does Windows Defender on Windows 8.1 provide same protection as on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-8.1, security, anti-virus, windows-defender

I'm concerned about reliablity of Windows Defender.I currently use Windows 8.1 and don't use any other antivirus programs. When I checked online, all the reviews of Windows Defender were that of the Windows 10 version, which looks like this-

[image]

But my Windows Defender looks like this-

[image]

I'm not complaining about the aesthetics and stuff, but we can clearly see there are some major differences. Though I recieve daily updates on the my one, is it comparable to a good Anti-Virus Program?

Comment: Windows Defender rose to fame when it was still called Microsoft Security Essentials. So yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 is now five years on and newer than Windows 8.1.

Windows Defender has been constantly improving and kept up to date for new viruses.

A couple of years ago, Windows Defender and Windows built EMET (Enhanced Mitigation Experience Toolkit) right into Windows 10.

Windows 8 does update security definitions, but (a) for sure install EMET V5 and (b) Windows 8 is coming to end of life and Windows 10 Defender will always be better.

Maybe it is time to upgrade to get all the security benefits.

With Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 up to V1607, I used Symantec Endpoint Protection Corporate. Consider something like this if remaining with Windows 8.1 .  Windows Defender by itself is great by itself with Windows 10 V1809 and beyond.

I think that if you wish the security benefits we get with Windows 10 V2004, upgrading is the way to do that.